# Manage Different Activity Logs in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Sorry if this question is out of interest. I need an idea of how can I manage the problem as below.

I'm working on a Laravel project where I have different activities like add note, send SMS, send email, upload document, etc. When the user acts on a particular activity, the data needs to be stored in the database.

I've created a different table for each activity because they have different values to store. After storing activities in the database, I need to display recent activity at the top of the page.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: You can mix Laravel Events, Laravel broadcast & notifications

Answer (score 2):

You have not provided any code or screenshot for your requirement.
So basically I can just suggest you an idea to achieve the functionality that you are looking for:

As per your requirement. I would like to suggest you to have 1 table for activity logs and other tables for different kind of activities like add note, send sms etc (depends upon your values).

So here is an overview of database fields that you need:

**First of all you just need to insert the data in the table in which you want to save. (for e.g notes, sms, call).
After the insertion in a table, you need to get the last inserted id from the table.**

**You can get it after performing save operation.** 
In Laravel, you just need to do the following:

Suppose you have saved the data as:
$notes->save();
now you can get the id of last inserted record with:
$aid=$notes->id;

**Now create a table activity_logs**
Next you need to insert the value of $aid into your activity_logs table
You should have 6 fields to save activity logs i.e:

(1) id (auto increment id with Primary key attribute)

(2) uid (saves the user id of each user)

(3) aid (Activity Id, in my example it is $aid)

(4) activity_name (this should be the name of the table like notes, sms, call etc)

(5) created_at

(6) updated_at

**Here is a guide to fetch the data of activities from all the tables:**

Get the data from activity_logs table first in foreach loop.
now in the loop you can get the data from the different tables by giving the value of activity_name as the table name in your query.

Thanks